# Oracle, count of distinct items by date

Tags: oracle, date, count

I need to get a count of items by date from field1 grouped by last update time. What I am looking for is how many times an item from field1 appears on a specific date for the last 30 days where field 2 = 0. This will be run every day so the date will roll. Field1 will be a number >0, field2 will be any number (negative and positive), last_upd_time will be a system time when the last update occurred. I don't need the time, only the date. My current query that returns all of the data is:

```
select field1, field2, trunc(last_upd_time)
from table 
where field2 = '0' and last_upd_time >= SYSDATE - 30
```

I have attempted to use count, group by, and group by/having. Not saying I was using them correctly, but I did try.

Comment: I have this now: select count (field1), field1, trunc(last_upd_time) AS D
from table 
where field2 > '0' and last_upd_time >= SYSDATE - 30
group by field1,  trunc(last_upd_time)                   This gives a list of field1 all but not a count of the total of field1 for each date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(last_upd_time,'DD-MM-YYYY') last_upd_time, COUNT(DISTINCT field1)
FROM table WHERE field2='0' AND
last_upd_time>=SYSDATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(last_upd_time,'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Comment: I received an error for the quotes around last_upd_time, changed those and receive and error stating " FROM not found where expected" at line 1 column 44 (location of the first quote in 'last_upd_time').

Comment: The syntax error was due to a spelling error of distinct. I corrected the query, please try again and vote up my answer if it worked.